# combining 2 renderers into one statement in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I already have a render for a grid that looks like this:

```js
                            me.processHealth({
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
                                    var str = '';
                                    if (value === 0)  {
                                        str = 'No';
                                    }

                                    if (value === 1)  {
                                        str = 'Yes!';
                                    }

                                    if (value === 2)  {
                                        str = 'Yes! Sub';
                                    }

                                    if (value === 3)  {
                                        str = 'Yes! Vice Chair';
                                    }

                                    if (value === 4)  {
                                        str = 'Yes! Chair';
                                    }

                                    return str;
                                },
```

That code changes the string depending on the result from the query.  I need to now add a renderer that also changes the background color depending on the same value.  This is the code for that (I do not know how to integrate the two together):

```js
renderer : function(value, meta) {
    if(parseInt(value) === 1) {
        meta.style = "background-color:green;";
    } else if(parseInt(value) === 2) {
        meta.style = "background-color:red;";
    }
    return value;
}
```

How would I integrate these 2 so that I change both the str and the bg color depending on those values?  Thanks

Comment: What's the problem with first setting the meta and then updating and returning the value in the same function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single `renderer` function can modify the metaData and return a value to be displayed:

```
me.processHealth({
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
    var str = '';
    if (value === 0)  {
        str = 'No';
    }

    if (value === 1)  {
        str = 'Yes!';
        metaData.style = "background-color:green;";
    }

    if (value === 2)  {
        str = 'Yes! Sub';
        metaData.style = "background-color:red;";
    }

    if (value === 3)  {
        str = 'Yes! Vice Chair';
    }

    if (value === 4)  {
        str = 'Yes! Chair';
    }

    return str;
    },
```

To add a CSS class to an entire row, you can use `getRowClass` in the viewConfig for the grid (see Sencha Docs [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.view.Table.html#method-getRowClass))

```
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store){
        return record.get("valid") ? "row-valid" : "row-error";
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked, but only for the cell, do you know how to do it for whole row?

Comment: Please see updated answer for adding a CSS class to an entire row.